# получить температуру и нагрузку Видеокарты. Cudafy

Tags: c#, загрузка, cuda, nvidia, нагрузка

как на C# в библиотеке cudafy получить информацию о температуре видеокарты, на сколько она загружена и возможно ли управлять её частотой и напряжением?